# PHP redirect to different page after form submit

Tags: php, sql, forms, redirect, header

Here's the first bit of my form code

```
 <form action="PHP/form.php" id="msform" method="post">

<fieldset id="owner_service">
<h2> ARE YOU A DOG OWNER OR SERVICE PROVIDER?</h2>
<legend>owner_service</legend>
<div class="owner_service">
<input type="radio" id="service" name="owner_service" value="service">
<label for ="service"><h5>SERVICE PROVIDER</h5></label>
<input type="radio" id="owner" name="owner_service" value="owner">
<label for ="owner"><h5>DOG OWNER</h5></label>
</div>
<input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" id="next" value="NEXT" />
</fieldset>
```

and here's the PHP

```
  <?php
session_start();

$servername = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 


$sql = "INSERT INTO pets (owner_service, Gender, Age, Size, Location, idealLocation, Service)
VALUES ('{$_POST['owner_service']}', '{$_POST['gender']}', '{$_POST['age']}', '{$_POST['size']}', '$locationCommaString', '{$_POST['ideal_location']}', '{$_POST['service']}')";



if($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}


?>
```

I've got my form running, so the results are in the database but what I want to do is bring the user to a new page depending on whether they clicked 'service provider' or 'dog owner'. I have no idea where to put the header because if I replace the if statement that I already have then the results won't show in my database.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['next'])) {

   // your code to save data 
  // after submit without db error

    if($_POST['owner_service'] == 'service') { // redirect page; }
    else if($_POST['owner_service'] == 'owner') { // redirect page; }

}
```

Put it in same Scope of echo "New record created successfully";

Answer (score 0):

The if statement goes after your query execution. Similar to what @laimingl suggested

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php
session_start();

$servername = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 


$sql = "INSERT INTO pets (owner_service, Gender, Age, Size, Location, idealLocation, Service)
VALUES ('{$_POST['owner_service']}', '{$_POST['gender']}', '{$_POST['age']}', '{$_POST['size']}', '$locationCommaString', '{$_POST['ideal_location']}', '{$_POST['service']}')";



if($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
   $serv = $_POST['owner_service'] ;
   switch($serv){
   case 'case 1':
          // Page redirection code here
   break;

   case 'case 2':
   // Page redirection code here
   break;





} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}


?>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for this, but when I try this code it just takes me to the 'echo; page and if I try to delete that code it takes me to an empty page. I'll show you the code I made


    if($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    
   $serv = $_POST['owner_service'];
   switch($serv){
   case 'case 1':
          header('Location: service_form.html');
  exit;
   break;

   case 'case 2':
     header('Location: owner_form.html');
  exit;
   break;
 }
  }else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

Answer (score -1):

Just change `input type="button"` to `input type="submit"`.